# Changing screen scale in LXDE

Tags: lxde, display-settings, lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu on a very old laptop, and it performs great! I know there is an option in Ubuntu unity desktop which allows changing the scale of what you see on screen. Since my old laptop is 1280×1024, I would like to scale things a bit down to get more real estate...but I could not find this option in LXDE.

I already tried smaller font size, but it is just not the right answer!

Comment: Is 1280x1024 your physical monitor size (in pixels) or just the resolution you are using? Check the output of `xrandr` to see if more dense pixelations are available.

Comment: Its the LCD's native resolution

Comment: For me .Xdefaults worked in 21.04:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49875344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1280x1024 and you need to scale down? My desktop screen is that resolution and I still use Dejavu Sans size 11/12! But I have bad sight.
There's no global "scaling" in LXDE; you change font size (in lxappearance), or icon size in the panel's size parameters (right click the panel and choose the panel parameter entry).

Answer (score 5):

There is an option to set global scale in LXDE.

Edit (or create) .Xresources in your home folder and set the dpi

```
Xft.dpi: 150
```

For my Dell XPS I have set it to 200 and works reasonably well